# Will moving blog posts from under an existing category to a new SUBcategory have a negative impact from an SEO POV?

Tags: seo, wordpress

As I'm having quite many article under one of my categories (Investments), I'm thinking about creating new subcategories (e.g. Real Estate Investments) under my main category and move some posts there.

Would moving some of my existing posts in the Investments category to a newly created subcategory (e.g. Real Estate Investments) impact my site negatively from an SEO point of view?

Please note: My URL structure does not contain category name, so that's not an issue. I'm thinking more about cannibalisation, duplicate content etc.

Comment: No, it will not impact your site negatively. If the website URL is the same as it was before. You really don't need to think about SEO, make sure your user find the category relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, yes it is a good idea to add subcategories if you have enough content that is relevant to the subcategory.

Besides SEO, it helps users find the content that is most relevant to them. It is the same logic for creating category pages - it condenses and makes relationships clear, for both people and search engines.

You would rather have those posts rank high for real estate investment searches, rather than in the middle, unseen, for general investment searches. Making their content grouping specific is a positive signal.